# Invalid asset source path

Tags: assets, error-message, error

After setting an asset resource I am receiving the "your source ' ' appears to be invalid." on the update indexes, and

```
Error uploading the file: The file system path '{basePath}/assets/images/' set for this source does not exist.` on the assets upload page.
```

My file structure is:

```
/var/www/
        craft/
        html/
            index.php
            assets/
                images/
```

I've tried all variations I can think of, ie:

```
{basePath}assets/images/
/assets/images/
/var/www/html/assets/images
```

I've ensured that the basepath is set correctly in `general.php` and i've ensured that ownership of the folders is set correctly.

Craft is installed on a digital ocean lamp droplet running 14.04. general.php looks like:

```
return array(

  // Use IP address of your droplet below
  'ip.address.of.droplet' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'http://ip.address.of.droplet/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => '/var/www/html/',
      'baseUrl'  => 'http://ip.address.of.droplet/',
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

the `general.php` file was setup for a multi environment but was missing

```
'*' => array(
),
```

as per the notice here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs

`{basePath}assets/images/` was the correct file system path once the array had been added.